# JQuery click() not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

In the following example, the top level links work fine but the links inside of the second level of the menu do not. The `li`s are inside the dropdown, yet when you click nothing happens. It will execute the hide command but will not show the desired `div` from the `if` statement. I've tried to use class selectors and straight ids but nothing works.

The code:

```js
 // Make buttons clickable
    $(".slideOut").hide();
    $("#mainText").show();
    // alert($('.selected').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);

    $(".navOpt").click(function() {
      // Remove selected from all others
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      $(".slideOut").hide();
      // Show appropriate div
      if ($(this).attr("id") == "main") {
        $("#mainText").show();
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("id") == "about") {
        $("#aboutText").show();
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("id") == "contact") {
        $("#contactText").show();
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("id") == "gallery") {
        $("#galleryText").show();
      }
      else if ($(this).child().child().attr("id") == "cakes") {
        $("#cakesText").show();
      }
    });

    $("#menu").hover(function() {
      $("#drop").show();
    });

    $("#cakes").click(function() {
      $("#cakesText").show();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sweet Remedies</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <span>Words</span>
    <h1 id="title">Sweet Remedies</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
      <nav id="menuList">
        <ul>
          <li id="main" class="navOpt selected"><a href="#">Main</a></li>
          <li id="about" class="navOpt"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li id="contact" class="navOpt"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li id="gallery" class="navOpt"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li id="menu" class="navOpt"><a href="#">Menu<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul id="drop">
              <li id="cakes" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Cakes</a></li>
              <li id="cupcakes" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Cupcakes</a></li>
              <li id="cookies" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
              <li id="pies" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Pies</a></li>
              <li id="extras" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="mainText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Whether it be preparing or eating the baked yummy goodness afterwards, sometimes thats all you need to make a bad day completely turn around... and thats what we're here for.</p>
      <p>Sweet Remedies is a privately oened online bakery here to satisfy all of your baking needs. It is our goal to present a delectable experience to soothe your sweet tooth and/or be your baking provider for any event you may have. Thank you for visiting our site and we hope you have a sweet day.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="aboutText" class="slideOut">
      <p>This text is in the wrong section.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contactText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Call me maybe?</p>
    </div>
    <div id="galleryText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Here are pictures of my things.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cakesText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Cakes are great and stuff.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cupcakesText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Cupcakes are super tasty.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cookiesText" class="slideOut">
      <p>I can make lots of cookies.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="piesText" class="slideOut">
      <p>I have never made a pie in my life.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="extrasText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Extra words for extra items.</p>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the menu that has Cakes, Cookies, ... Not working?

Comment: the menu drops but when one is clicked the div with the explanation dowsnt appear. The others work fine just not the sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplify your code .and use **.not('#menu.navOpt')**

instead of doing all that if statments you can just get the clicked element ID and use it to show his specific div

```
// Make buttons clickable
$(".slideOut, #mainText, #drop").hide();
// alert($('.selected').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
    // use .not('#menu.navOpt') to make #menu not clickable you just need it to show the submenu on hover
    $(".navOpt").not('#menu.navOpt').click(function() {
      // Remove selected from all others
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      var getId = $(this).attr("id");  // get this element ID
        $('.slideOut').hide(); // hide all divs with class slideOut
        $('#'+getId+'Text').show(); // use the ID to show its div
    });

    $("#menu").hover(function() {
          $("#drop").show();
        });

    $("#cakes").on('click',function() {
        $('.slideOut').hide();
      $("#cakesText").show();
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qgx7wgzc/)

Comment: I like simplified code. Not a JQuery expert myself. I can see what's wrong with the code. But you deserve upvotes and to be marked as answer if you explain the what your code does.

Comment: @Mouser I got your point man .. but honestly .. sometime in jquery I feel that the code explain itself  .. anyway I tried to make comments in code maybe it help .. Thanks :)

Comment: i got this all in still the submenu never pops when i click one

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Make buttons clickable
    $(".slideOut").hide();
    $("#mainText").show();
    // alert($('.selected').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);

    $(".navOpt").click(function(e) {

      // Remove selected from all others
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      $(".slideOut").hide();
      // Show appropriate div
      if ($(this).attr("id") == "main") {
        $("#mainText").show();
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("id") == "about") {
        $("#aboutText").show();
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("id") == "contact") {
        $("#contactText").show();
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("id") == "gallery") {
        $("#galleryText").show();
      }
      else if ($(e.target).closest("li").attr("id") == "cakes") {
       $("#cakesText").show();
      }
    });

    $("#menu").hover(function() {
      $("#drop").show();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sweet Remedies</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <span>Words</span>
    <h1 id="title">Sweet Remedies</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
      <nav id="menuList">
        <ul>
          <li id="main" class="navOpt selected"><a href="#">Main</a></li>
          <li id="about" class="navOpt"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li id="contact" class="navOpt"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li id="gallery" class="navOpt"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li id="menu" class="navOpt"><a href="#">Menu<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul id="drop">
              <li id="cakes" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Cakes</a></li>
              <li id="cupcakes" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Cupcakes</a></li>
              <li id="cookies" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
              <li id="pies" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Pies</a></li>
              <li id="extras" class="subMenu"><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="mainText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Whether it be preparing or eating the baked yummy goodness afterwards, sometimes thats all you need to make a bad day completely turn around... and thats what we're here for.</p>
      <p>Sweet Remedies is a privately oened online bakery here to satisfy all of your baking needs. It is our goal to present a delectable experience to soothe your sweet tooth and/or be your baking provider for any event you may have. Thank you for visiting our site and we hope you have a sweet day.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="aboutText" class="slideOut">
      <p>This text is in the wrong section.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contactText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Call me maybe?</p>
    </div>
    <div id="galleryText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Here are pictures of my things.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cakesText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Cakes are great and stuff.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cupcakesText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Cupcakes are super tasty.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cookiesText" class="slideOut">
      <p>I can make lots of cookies.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="piesText" class="slideOut">
      <p>I have never made a pie in my life.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="extrasText" class="slideOut">
      <p>Extra words for extra items.</p>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`child` isn't a jQuery function, [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) is. However if you replace child with `children` this condition will always render true, due to the nature of *jQuery*. It will loop all elements and then checks if there is one with id `cakes`. It happens on all clicks.

So we need to check if the clicked element is the one. Therefor we can use the event object.

Use `e` in the function arguments as a reference to the event. This will refer to the event triggered. `target` is the a element which was clicked upon. Wrap it inside a jQuery function. Find its parent/or itself with [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and collect. the id.

`$(e.target).closest("li").attr("id")`

This will be correct.

Comment: sorry this is litterally my second website, not sure if i should use that in the if else statement or write something completely different

Answer (score 0):

You're still clicking an anchor tag nested inside `.navOpt` which has `href="#"` and triggers a page refresh. That's also why the example jumps to the top of the page.

Change

```
<li id="menu" class="navOpt"><a href="#">Menu<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
```

to

```
<li id="menu" class="navOpt"><span class="menu-link>Menu<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></span>
```

Obviously any css targeting the `<a>` that is now a span won't work. Target a class instead that's applied to both `<a>` and `<span>`.